# Rails nested form with cocoon appears multiple times, but doesn't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using the `cocoon` gem in a Rails4 app to create a nested form
dynamically. Each Lease object my have zero or more MonthlyCharge
objects associated with it. (I.e., the Lease model `has_many
:monthly_charges`, and the MonthlyCharge model `belongs_to :lease`.)

I have a form for leases in `app/views/leases/_form.html.erb` that
calls monthly charges:

```
 <h3>Monthly Charges</h3>
 <div id="monthly_charges">
    <%= f.fields_for :monthly_charges do |monthly_charge| %>
        <%= render 'monthly_charge_fields', :f => monthly_charge %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association "Add a Monthly Charge", f, :monthly_charges %>
    </div>
 </div>
```

But when I click on "Add a Monthly Charge", three sets of form fields
appear, rather than one.

On top of that, no matter if I fill out the form for one monthly
charge or not, and regardless of whether I click on "Remove Charge"
for the others, rails doesn't save the monthly charge.

Gist is
[here](https://gist.github.com/amp108/e8f8093a806ba3925513db55307c9ee0).

What can I possibly be doing wrong? It was suggested that I might be
calling the cocoon js file more than once, but I've searched through
the source tree and haven't found any but a single reference to it, in
`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. Any input appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a conflict between turbolinks and including your application.js in the wrong place? It should be included inside the `head`, otherwise the `application.js` is loaded multiple times (when loading pages/navigating ...)

Comment: nathanvda, you are correct. `application.js` was being loaded multiple times. It makes me wonder why there isn't a common `#ifndef`-style mechanism or convention to prevent multiple inclusion in javascript. (Or if there is one, I'm unaware of it.)

Comment: That's a weird thing to say. Just include the application js in the head and it is not reloaded. So there is a mechanism. Also you do not need to use turbolinks, while it gives very impressive speedups, it is a little easier if you don't. Do you know turbolinks and what it does? https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks